# Inherited variables are not displaying in the subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm having an issue with the inherited variables not displaying in the subclass.

Heres the code...

```
// Class to instantiate and call

public class UseOrder 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Instantiate classes
        Order objOrder=new Order();
        ShippedOrder objShip=new ShippedOrder();
        //Promt for data
        objOrder.SetName();
        objOrder.SetNum();
        objOrder.SetPrice();
        objOrder.SetQuantity();
        // Display
        objShip.Display();
    }

}
//Heres the parent class

public class Order 
{

    //Declare variables
    public String CustName;
    public int CustNum,QuantityOrdered;
    public double Price,TotalPrice;
    //Assign Variables using set methods
    public void SetName()
    {
        this.CustName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer Name");
    }
    public void SetNum()
    {
        this.CustNum=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer number"));
    }
    public void SetQuantity()
    {
        this.QuantityOrdered=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter quanntity ordered"));
    }
    public void SetPrice()
    {
        this.Price=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter product price"));
    }
    //Get methods for these variables
    public String GetName()
    {
        return CustName;
    }
    public int GetNum()
    {
        return CustNum;
    }
    public int GetQuantity()
    {
        return QuantityOrdered;
    }
    public double GetPrice()
    {
        return Price;
    }
    //Method to calculate Total Price
    public double ComputePrice()
    {
        return TotalPrice=QuantityOrdered*Price;
    }
    // Method to display
    public void Display()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,CustName+" with customer number "+CustNum+" ordered "+QuantityOrdered+" products. \nThe price for one unit is " + Price+" and the total price is "+ComputePrice());
    }
}
 and heres the subclass

public class ShippedOrder extends Order
{

    //Shipping and handling value
    private double ShipFee=4.00;
    // method to override ComputePrice in Order
    public double ComputePrice()
    {
        return super.TotalPrice=(super.QuantityOrdered*super.Price)+ShipFee;
    }
    //Display the data
    public void Display()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,super.GetName()+" with customer number "+super.GetNum()+" ordered "+super.GetQuantity()+" products. \nThe price for one unit is " + super.GetPrice()+" and the total price is "+ComputePrice());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You populate a different object than you're displaying, so no wonder you get no values. You should change main to

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // Instantiate classes
    ShippedOrder objShip=new ShippedOrder();
    //Promt for data
    objShip.SetName();
    objShip.SetNum();
    objShip.SetPrice();
    objShip.SetQuantity();
    // Display
    objShip.Display();
}
```

because every `ShippedOrder` is also an `Order`.

Comment: I understand now what I did wrong, Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // Instantiate classes
    Order objOrder=new Order();
    ShippedOrder objShip=new ShippedOrder();
    //Promt for data
    objOrder.SetName();
    objOrder.SetNum();
    objOrder.SetPrice();
    objOrder.SetQuantity();
    // Display
    objShip.Display();
}
```

You never set anything in objShip (the derived class). All your pre-display() method invocations were on objOrder, a different object.

Maybe you meant:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // Instantiate classes
    Order objOrder=new ShippedOrder();
    //Promt for data
    objOrder.SetName();
    objOrder.SetNum();
    objOrder.SetPrice();
    objOrder.SetQuantity();
    // Display
    objOrder.Display();
}
```

Comment: I see what I've done wrong, Thanks for your answer :]

Answer (score 0):

objShip and objOrder are separate from one another. When you change order, it will not change ship as they are different objects. You need to call the methods on objShip in this case if you want to display it from that.

```
ShippedOrder objShip = new ShippedOrder();
    objShip.SetName();
    objShip.SetNum();
    objShip.SetPrice();
    objShip.SetQuantity();

    objShip.Display();
```

and remove objOrder completely.

Comment: I see now what I did wrong, Thanks for your quick answer :]